# LaserJet M1522nF firmware was corrupted during the update

Tags: hardware, printing, hp, firmware

I have a [LaserJet M1522nF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hewlett-Packard_products#LaserJet_printers_.28color_and_monochrome.29), and the problem when I working on is that it is freezing every time so I decide to update the firmware. During the updating the device was down because of electricity so I turned it on again and there is a message on the small screen saing

> HEWLETT-PACKARD >>

After nothing appeared on screen the device seems to be blocked or the firmware was corrupted.

Now, how can I reset the update of firmware or how can I reinstall it?

Comment: Sometimes, you can re-flash devices like this over JTAG, but I don't have any experience with this particular printer.  Otherwise, you might have to replace the board.  Also, I think you have the wrong model number.  I can't find that printer, even by Googling for it.

Comment: I'd call HP to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply here is the link for this if http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3442754&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3442750&lang=en&cc=us if this case how can I re-flash it

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the same printer. Did you get a solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The exact same thing happened with the same printer model to a client of mine. We tried waiting for a few days like that, because it sometimes helps in restoring failed flashes on some Xerox printers, but it didn't help with this HP printer. My advice was to simply call HP.